# Java Code to calculate the Packet Length of a MQTT Message

Tags: mqtt, java-io

Guidance needed to calculate the packet length of a MQTT Message. Need to calcuate this every message i.e a MQTT Control Message without a payload or variable header as well as one with Payload/ variable header.

Tried looking into netty, but that seems to be overkill as my application is just a websocket application which acts like a proxy between a mobile device and a back end application send MQTT message to the device. So prefer the usage of JSE classes.

Thanks

Comment: 1) Have you read the MQTT spec? 2) Why can't you use an existing MQTT library like Paho? 3) What have you already tried?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Reading MQTT spec is in my todo. Too packed up with assignments. I have not used Paho or other libraries. Basically my web application is a java websocket application which acts as a proxy between two a serversocker and web-socket client communication with my web socket end point in between. There is no need for deciphering the to and fro traffic. I am using javax.nio.Channel read from the server socket and write to the web socket.  Do you think , in such scenario , will using a MQTT library give a performance boost . Thanks ?